# Unable to login to ghcr.io docker registry (service unavailable)

Tags: docker, github

I was running docker login command in powershell. I've tried with both PAT and password, but it does not work.

```
Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable
```

As a side note, earlier I was successfully logging in to **gchr**.io because I made a typo. So I attempted this:

```
docker login gchr.io/ -u whatever -p adokwoakdoakwodkawd
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Login Succeeded
```

This seems strange to me. Login succeeded with fake credentials? Maybe it's something fishy. Anyway, why can't I reach the real ghcr.io? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Probably late for you by now but **gchr.io** is not the right domain for GitHub Container Registry. I tested with PAT and it seems to work. Also, make sure you have the right scopes (write packages) set before making a PAT to push the package to **ghcr.io**